# Angular, Cannot find module typeahead-basic

Tags: angular, angular6

I'm using the Angular 6 versions. I added '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap' in my app module. While importing the typeahead module I'm getting an error below.

```
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { NgbdTypeaheadBasic } from './typeahead-basic';
```

error

```
Cannot find module './typeahead-basic' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)
```

Answer (score 0):

Without any code to go on, I'm just assuming that you haven't actually created the component you're trying to import, or the import path is incorrect.

Check [this stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/run?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftypeahead-basic.ts) for a correct implementation.

Basically you need a component, something like:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {debounceTime, distinctUntilChanged, map} from 'rxjs/operators';

const states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'American Samoa', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California', 'Colorado',
  'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'District Of Columbia', 'Federated States Of Micronesia', 'Florida', 'Georgia',
  'Guam', 'Hawaii', 'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana', 'Maine',
  'Marshall Islands', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota', 'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana',
  'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire', 'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Carolina', 'North Dakota',
  'Northern Mariana Islands', 'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Palau', 'Pennsylvania', 'Puerto Rico', 'Rhode Island',
  'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont', 'Virgin Islands', 'Virginia',
  'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming'];

@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-typeahead-basic',
  templateUrl: './typeahead-basic.html',
  styles: [`.form-control { width: 300px; }`]
})
export class NgbdTypeaheadBasic {
  public model: any;

  search = (text$: Observable<string>) =>
    text$.pipe(
      debounceTime(200),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      map(term => term.length < 2 ? []
        : states.filter(v => v.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) > -1).slice(0, 10))
    )

}
```

Comment: my component name is project-list.component.ts and HTML. But it giving an error in app.module.ts. I mentioned the question. Read the question clearly.